# Write a function that should return a new string, containing only the words that don't have the letter "e" in them in javascript

Tags: javascript, array-filter

what am I doing wrong in the code that I mentioned below?

My outputs are [ 'What', 'time', 'is', 'it', 'everyone?' ] and [ 'building' ]. These outputs should be string because I used join method. Also the first output is totally wrong.

```js
let removeEWords = function(sentence) {
  debugger
  let arrayedSentence = sentence.split(" ");
  let newArr = [];
  return arrayedSentence.filter(function(el) {
    if (!el.includes("e")) {
      newArr.push(el);
    }
    return newArr.join(" ");
  })

};
console.log(removeEWords('What time is it everyone?')); // 'What is it'
console.log(removeEWords('Enter the building')); // 'building'
```

Comment: For one, you're using `filter` as if it's `map`...

Comment: @mplungjan actually not.  You do not return values from `forEach`.

Comment: Ok,  it is not a map if he did what he had in mind and returned the newArr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ['filter'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and not add to an array - you are using `filter` as a forEach

```js
const removeEWords = sentence => sentence
  .split(" ")
  .filter(word => !word.includes("e")) // this returns true to return or false to drop
  .join(" ");
console.log(removeEWords('What time is it everyone?')); // 'What is it'
console.log(removeEWords('Enter the building')); // 'building'
```

Comment: @UBO Thanks for accepting my answer. It was the first and it is correct, but someone decided to vote it down anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The way `.filter()` works on an array is you need to return either `true` or `false`. True = Keep, False = leave;

Knowing this, you can refactor this really simply by just doing this:

```js
let removeEWords =  (sentence) => sentence.split(" ").filter((el) => !el.includes("e")).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array of elements that *pass the test* (ie `true/false`) provided in the callback - there's no need for a temporary array that push elements into. So all you need to do is `return !word.includes('e');` to return a word that doesn't include `e`.

Note: I've called the variable `word` as it makes the callback easier to read.

```js
function removeEWords(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').filter(word => {
    return !word.includes('e');
  })
};

console.log(removeEWords('What time is it everyone?'));
console.log(removeEWords('Enter the building'));
```